# Jquery: trouble selecting by class

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting query to select a element by a class.  I'm trying to select a element within a form and hide it.

This works if I just have one class on the element I want to hide but if I have two or more classes, it won't add the hide class.

css

```
.hide {display: none;}
```

html

```
<form id="frm">    
    <span class="hideme styledspan">This will be hidden</span>
</form>
```

script

```
$("#btn_hide").click(function () {
     $("#frm .hideme").addClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: I think you must use `.hide {display: none;}` right.?

Comment: a fiddle could help. also are you sure you that you are seleciting the btn_hide properly? maybe it should be .btn_hide? also check @RajaprabhuAravindasamy 's comment

Comment: Your selector `btn_hide` doesn't seem correct.  Perhaps it should be `.btn_hide`? (Or `#btn_hide` if an ID) However the selector `#frm .hideme` looks fine.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is set to none on my end.  I just tried to simplify it on here.  I have updated the css in my post.

Comment: And are ***all*** of those `hideme` elements *inside* the `#frm` element, and there's only one single `#frm` element ?

Comment: also make sure other classes (i.e. `styledspan`) does not override the display of the span with something like `display:block !important`

Comment: What is the CSS for `styledspan` and `hideme`?

Comment: replicate issue on jsFiddle if you can

Answer (score 1):

You may need to ensure you run that script after the DOM is loaded:

```
$(function(){
  $("#btn_hide").click(function () {
     $("#frm .hideme").addClass("hide");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FsdMG/

Answer (score 0):

Just go directly with the funciton `hide`, dont add a class like that. Erase your css, you dont need it and change your code to:

```
$("#btn_hide").click(function () {
 $("#frm .hideme").hide();
});
```

Another thing, you need to run the function within a `document.ready` function so the event is added. I rather create a function and call it via HTML simply using the onClick attribute.

Comment: Then why didn't .addClass('hide') work in op's context.?

Comment: Oh, this is old but hopefully I can clear it out. The class that should be added is "hidden" not "hide"

Answer (score 0):

check this demo link:-http://jsfiddle.net/8tPyJ/

css code

`.hide {display: none;}`

html code

```
    <span class="hideme styledspan">This will not be hidden</span>
<form id="frm">    
    <span class="hideme styledspan">This will be hidden</span><br/>
    <span class="hideme styledspan">This will be hidden</span>
</form>
<input type="button" id="btn_hide" value="data">
```

jquery code:-

```
$("#btn_hide").click(function () {
     $("#frm .hideme").addClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: How is this different from the OP's code?